# Acs Reader acr122 with smartcardio, following error SCARD_E_READER_UNAVAILABLE occures if we don't start ACR122UTool before

Tags: java, nfc

I am using smartcardio api for writing data from the NFC ACR 122u reader to a Android phone

This is a code I am using :

```
TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();

if (terminals==null || terminals.size()==0) {
    le.warn("nfcReaderPresent no terminal found");
    return false;
}

terminal = terminals.get(0);
try {
    boolean res=terminal.waitForCardPresent(5*1000);
    if (res)
        interrupt=true;
}
catch(Exception p) {
    le.error("pushData p="+p);
    le.fatal(p);
}

if (terminal.isCardPresent()) {
    card = terminal.connect("*");//it seems always to be T=1

    ATR atr=card.getATR();
    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
    le.debug("card: " + card+" channel="+channel+"  atr="+ByteArrayToHexString(atr.getBytes()));

    //ADPU command
    byte getDataCmd[]={(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xCA,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00};
    sendCommand(getDataCmd,channel);
...
```

The error `javax.smartcardio.CardException: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: SCARD_E_READER_UNAVAILABLE` occurs before sending APDU command.

When I start before the tool ACR122UTool and just click on Connect, everything works fine. (ACR122uTool is not needed anymore)
It seems that the acs tool initializes the device.

Any help will be greatly appreciated